# printing postorder from given inorder and preorder

Tags: c++, arrays, recursion, binary-tree

the following code for printing postorder from given preorder and inorder is showing segmentation fault. can u please explain why??

```
int j=0;
void post_order(int in[],int pre[],int start,int end){
    if(start>end) {
        return;
    }
    int i;
    for(int i=start;i<=end;i++){
        if(pre[j]==in[i]){
            break;
        }
    }

    j++;
    post_order(in,pre,start,i-1);
    post_order(in,pre,i+1,end);
    cout<<in[i]<<" ";
}
void printPostOrder(int in[], int pre[], int n)
{
//Your code here
int start=0;
int end = n-1;
post_order(in,pre,start,end);

}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre], including sample input which demonstrates the problem.

Comment: you have been provided with two array one representing preorder and other inorder traversal of tree as shown: preorder_array: 1 2 4 5 3 6    inorder_array: 4 2 5 1 3 6

Comment: I don't get the point of your comment. Consider to [edit] your question for adding information, instead of hiding it down here in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

```cpp
    int i;  //< uninitialised

    //   V--- a new variable called 'i'
    for(int i=start;i<=end;i++){
        if(pre[j]==in[i]){
            break;
        }
    }


    // this will probably crash (i hasn't been initialised yet!)
    cout<<in[i]<<" ";
```

Comment: so if I intialize i with say i=start will it show correct result??

Comment: for(i=start;i<=end;i++) //< remove int from here?

Comment: it is still giving segmentation fault